# Show a form with values after submiting a form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form from which i am submitting user name , net i want to show all the details in sap rate form but don't want to load a different page.
please help

Comment: any attempt you made so far?

Comment: Use ajax then and prevent FORM to submit

Answer (score 0):

Not sure,but this could help you,instead of making new form,it will be beneficial for saving full form and then displaying it

use

```
var htmldata=$("#yourformid").html();
```

to store data.

and then pass this variable through jquery to the form,this will show up with the form along with its values.
like

```
$('#ur div id').text(htmldata);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking like login and then display that details of the user in another form, you would need to write some javascript along with your html.

```
<form id="login_form" action="/login" method="post">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<form id="new_form">
    <input type="text" name="value1" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax("/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        data: $("#login_form").serialize(),
        success: function (response, status) {
            $("#new_form").find("input").val(reponse["value1"]);
        },
        error: function (response, status) {
        }
    });
});
```

Is this something that you were looking for?